# Scheme - How do I loop an anonymous function?

Tags: function, loops, scheme, higher-order-functions, anonymous

I have been trying to convert a normal function into a higher order function that does the same thing. The function is supposed to take a operator as a argument and then apply that operator to each and every element in a list. For example if I choose the operator "+" it would return the sum of all the elements in a list.

Normal version of function:

```
(define (accumulate proc id lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) id)
    ((eqv? (cdr lst) '()) (car lst))
    (else (proc (car lst) (accumulate proc id (cdr lst))))))
```

Higher order version of function (incomplete):

```
(define (acc-proc proc id)
(lambda (lst)
(cond ((null? lst) id)
      ((null? (cdr lst)) (car lst))
      (else
```

In the normal function I am using a recursive call to loop it but I can't loop the higher order function because it doesn't have lst as an argument. Instead the argument lst is in the anonymous lambda procedure.

I am new to Scheme so forgive me if my solutions are bad. Maybe there is a better way to do this without looping? I have no idea what to put into that else statement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there's a bug in your original function: your second case means that you're ignoring `id` for everything except the empty list:

```
> (accumulate + 34 '(1 2 3))
6
> (accumulate + 34 '())
34
```

You only need two cases; empty and non-empty lists.

For the actual problem: if the "anonymous" part isn't essential, you can use a local named function:

```
(define (acc-proc proc id)
  (define (recurse lst)
    (if (null? lst)
        id
        (proc (car lst) (recurse (cdr lst)))))
  recurse)
```

If anonymousity is important, you need to take the lambda calculus route and use a fixpoint combinator.

Comment: That isn't a bug. The second case is supposed to ignore the id. If list is empty it will return id.

Comment: (accumulate + 0 '())

Comment: @Schytheron Yes, but `(accumulate + 34 '(1 2 3))` should be 40, not 6. `id` is the "starting point" for all lists, not just the empty one.

Comment: Damn it! I keep clicking ENTER and posting comments before finishing them. (accumulate + 0 '()) = 0. (accumulate + 0 '(5)) = 5.

Comment: This is task I was given in School and in the task description is says that id should be returned if list is empty so... I don't know... just following what it says.

Comment: @Schytheron and the task describes what should happen if it's the step before empty list like you have in your code?

Comment: @Schytheron My version (which is the "standard" interpretation of what `accumulate` does) also returns `id` if the list is empty. Does your description say that you should ignore `id` if the list isn't empty? (Note that "if the list is empty, the result is id" does not imply that.)

Comment: It says: "If there is only one element in the list then the first element should be returned. If the list has more than one element proc should be applied to the first element and the result of accumulate for the rest of the list"

Comment: @Schytheron Wow. That's ... "decidedly non-standard" (to avoid swearing) and not the way most people expect `accumulate` to work. Usually, the variant you're describing doesn't have an identity parameter, and doesn't allow the empty list. I'm sure you can apply my suggestion to your solution in order to conform to that specification, though.